# Как в PHP передать файл при POST запросе на другой сайт по url

Tags: php, post, curl, php-curl

Мне нужно выполнить POST запрос на другой сайт, передать content-type и файл. Не могу понять как это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$url = '...';
$image = '...';
$post_fields = array(
    PHP_VERSION_ID < 50500 ? '@' . $image : new CURLFile($image, 'image/jpeg'),
    // ...
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post_fields,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'),
    // ...
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```